# must sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(size_t)?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

There was a question here about equality of `sizeof(size_t)` and `sizeof(void*)` and the accepted answer was that they are not guaranteed to be equal.

But at least, must it be that:

`sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(size_t)`

I think so.  Because, take the largest stored object possible in a given C implementation, of size `S`. Now, the storage area can be thought of as array of bytes of size `S`. Therefore, there must be a pointer to each byte, and all these pointers are comparable and different. Therefore, the number of distinct elements of type `void*`, must be at least, the largest number of type `size_t`, which is unsigned integer type. Thus `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(size_t)` .

Is my reasoning making sense or not?

Comment: Closely related [size_t vs. uintptr_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1464174/11082165)

Comment: I don't see anything in the standard preventing, say, 48-bit pointers and 64-bit `size_t`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55204639

Comment: Your logic assumes `size_t` has *exactly* enough bits to represent the largest possible size. It could have more.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica  oh I see thank you, please make it an answer I will accept it

Comment: [Is sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void*) always true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18810800/995714), [Is size of size_t always equal to the size of void * (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19713642/995714)

Comment: I'll go ahead and close as dupe, since so far the answer/comments here are the same as in the linked dupe target.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my reasoning making sense or not?

The problem with your reeasoning is that you assume that the size of the largest object possible equals SIZE_MAX. But that's not true. If you do

```
void* p = malloc(SIZE_MAX);
```

you will (most likely) get a NULL pointer back.

You may also get warnings like:

```
main.cpp:48:15: warning: argument 1 value '18446744073709551615' exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Walloc-size-larger-than=]
   48 |     void* p = malloc(SIZE_MAX);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Since the maximum object size isn't (always) SIZE_MAX you can't use the value of SIZE_MAX to argue about the size of pointers.

BTW: Some CPU implementation that uses 64 bit pointers at the SW level may not have 64 bit at the HW level. Instead some bits are just treated as all-ones/all-zeros.